# How to make and apply changes to Jan Berkel's android-plugin?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

As the title says, I'm wondering how to apply changes to [Jan Berkel's SBT Android Plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin).

I know what it says there...

```
$ git clone git://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin.git
$ cd android-plugin
$ sbt publish-local
```

... and I did that and got this in `/target/scala-2.9.1/sbt-0.11.3/`

```
/api/
/cache/
/classes/
/resource_managed/
/ivy-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.xml
/sbt-android-plugin-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
/sbt-android-plugin-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
/sbt-android-plugin-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
```

My question is, how to apply those changes to my current SBT.

BTW, I'm using **Windows 7** (I know, I know... :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After publish-local you should have it in your local ivy cache and you can use it. Have you checked if it is in there?

Comment: Yups, it's there. Is that it? Or do I need to do anything else?